# Where is permission tap on TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

Hi I'm new on TestFlight i want to add provisioning profile to existing project but i can't find permission tap. I have already add ipa file Here is a screen image. please help

[image]

thanks

Comment: You have to go into a specific build first.

Comment: ooo sorry sorry i should enter inside existing build... and thanks